# Html video display - incorrect size?

Tags: html, iframe, src

I am trying to embed a YouTube video in an HTML page with an `iframe`. I am in doubts (the size is wrong). The link for the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqQ6gy-tT9Y?autoplay=1

My html code :

```
<section id="test">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqQ6gy-tT9Y?
                autoplay=1" width="420" height="315"  align="center">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have copied the embed code from youtube:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EqQ6gy-tT9Y?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Note that the link is:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/EqQ6gy-tT9Y

and not

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqQ6gy-tT9Y

Your code should be:

```
<section id="test">
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EqQ6gy-tT9Y?autoplay=1" width="420" height="315"  align="center">
                    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
                </iframe>

                </div>
  </section>
```

Btw.: You had a line-break in the `<iframe src="">` property, i dont know if you just did that for readability, but its causes problems, keep linebreaks outside of html element properties